# superclass mismatch for class AddBraintreeIdToTransactionBraintreeInfos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, superclass

My site is working fine on my localhost.  When I try to do a database migration with heroku, I get the following error:

```
superclass mismatch for class AddBraintreeIdToTransactionBraintreeInfos
```

Here are the two migration files.  They are running in the order I display them:

1.

```
class CreateTransactionBraintreeInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :transaction_braintree_infos do |t|
      t.belongs_to :task, index: true
      t.string :order_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

2.

```
class AddBraintreeIdToTransactionBraintreeInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :transaction_braintree_infos, :braintree_id, :string
  end
end
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is `AddBraintreeIdToTransactionBraintreeInfos` declared anywhere else in your project?

Comment: check to make sure you don't have another AddBraintreeIDToTransactionBraintreeInfos definition hanging around somewhere. it could be that you've removed a file locally but it was still stored in git and therefore made it to heroku.

Comment: I can't find it anywhere else in the project.  I might have deleted a migration a few days ago though, I can't remember.  If thats the case, what should I do.  My git is a clean directory (meaning it is up to date).

Comment: Uri Agassi. that was the issue.  Thanks a lot.